# How to assign input data to another variable in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is what I have:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model.number="money">
        <p>{{money}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
name: 'MyComponent',
  data () {
    return {
        money: 0
    }
  }
</script>
```

After getting the input value, if I change the value of `money` in data by some methods , how can I get the original input value? Is it a good practice? Should I assign the input value to another variable?

Comment: If by `change money in data by some methods` means returns a value that is based on `money` property, you can use `computed` property in Vue.

Comment: It's ideal that there is a way to make a duplicate of the input value of money

Comment: I want to do something like computedMoney: money in data

Comment: Why do you want to make a duplicate of the input value of `money`? If you want to display something which value is calculated by `money` like {{ computedMoney }}, you can do it as Michael suggested. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: In fact, I want to get an input value and use it as the length of an array. I have a reduceLength method for reducing the length of the array, that's why I want a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. As Mengo commented above, you can keep the original value and then also have a computed value based on the input value by doing something like this:

```
  data: {
    money: 0
  },
  computed: {
    computedMoney() {
      return this.money + this.money * 0.0825;
    }
  }
```

See working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VEajJK

Comment: Thank you for answers. I have methods for modifying the value of money, but I don't need those methods to return anything, just change the value of money without affecting the original input.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be too long for a comment, so I'll put my answer here. Based on my understanding of your goal.

```
data: {
  lengthInput: 0,
  original: [1,2,3],
},
computed: {
  calculated() {
    return this.original.slice(this.lengthInput);
  }
}
```

Then you can access the result as `this.calculated` or `<li v-for="i in calculated" :key="i">{{ i }}</li>` in template